# How to use GUID as Primary Key with System.Data.Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm not saying it's advisable, but sometimes you inherit something which just needs to work. In this case it's Guids for Primary Keys...

Out of the box, you'll get an error about System.Guid not working with byte[] (or String if you're using BinaryGUID=False).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this, you need to intercept byte[] arrays (or strings) and instead return Guid type. This is possible with the System.Data.Sqlite provider.

First

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
```

Then, put this in the constructor of your code-first db context:

```
var con = (SQLiteConnection)base.Database.Connection;
var bind = System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteTypeCallbacks.Create(
                null, 
                new SQLiteReadValueCallback(GuidInterceptor), null, null);
con.SetTypeCallbacks("uniqueidentifier", bind);
con.SetTypeCallbacks("", bind); //Sometimes, the system just doesn't know
con.Flags |= SQLiteConnectionFlags.UseConnectionReadValueCallbacks;
```

And then this is the magic function:

```
    private void GuidInterceptor(SQLiteConvert convert, SQLiteDataReader reader, SQLiteConnectionFlags flags, SQLiteReadEventArgs args, string typename, int index, object userdata, out bool complete)
    {
        complete = false;
        if (typename == "uniqueidentifier")
        {
            var e = (SQLiteReadValueEventArgs)args;

            var o = reader.GetGuid(index);
            e.Value.Value = o;
            e.Value.GuidValue = o;
            complete = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var o = reader.GetValue(index);
            if (o is byte[])
            {
                var b = (byte[])o;
                if (b.Length == 16)
                {
                    var e = (SQLiteReadValueEventArgs)args;
                    var g = new Guid(b);
                    e.Value.Value = g;
                    e.Value.GuidValue = g;
                    complete = true;
                }
            }
            else if (o is string)
            {
                var s = (string)o;
                if (s.Length == 36)
                {
                    var e = (SQLiteReadValueEventArgs)args;
                    var goGuid = (e.MethodName == "GetGuid");
                    if (!goGuid)
                        goGuid = (s[8] == '-' && s[13] == '-' && s[18] == '-' && s[23] == '-');

                    Guid g;
                    if (goGuid && Guid.TryParse(s, out g))
                    {
                        e.Value.Value = g;
                        e.Value.GuidValue = g;
                        complete = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

That only fixes reading in of data. If you try to `.Where()` on a Guid member, and you're using `BinaryGUID=True` no rows will be returned (when there should be). For now, you'll need `BinaryGUID=False`, which does take up more space, but it's a simple solution.

If you can help it, try and define your Guid properties instead as:

```
[Key]
[MaxLength(16)]
[MinLength(16)]
public byte[] AccountUserId { get; set; }
```

You'll be forced to call `guidValue.ToByteArray()` in your application layer. You might be able to create some helpers to you're not having to call that function. Having your own custom function proxy for creating and parsing Guids may help, so you can easily change the implementation.

In my case, I don't have the luxury of time to convert all the Guid properties and usages to `byte[]`